# Is there any other way to deploy in SharePoint other than wsps?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

We always deploy our solution as wsps in UAT and Prod.
Our solution has 5 projects.
For example:
If we make any change in any .cs file,is it necessary to deploy wsp everytime or is there any other way out we can achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any other way. If you have changes in your WSP, deploy the wsp and update the solution with Update-SPSolution.

If there are non-serverside interpreted files in your solutions (such as javascripts, images, html-files, or other assets), you can edit them directly on the server in the 15 hive or any other location where they were deployed but i would strongly discourage this approach.